# heroku pipeline missing 'test' stage option

Tags: heroku, pipeline

The Heroku docs states ...

> Your Heroku app runs in at least two environments:
>
> On your local machine (i.e., development).
> Deployed to the Heroku platform (i.e., production)
> Ideally, your app should run in two additional environments:
>
> Test, for running the app’s test suite safely in isolation
> Staging, for running a new build of the app in a production-like > setting before promoting it

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/multiple-environments#managing-staging-and-production-configurations

however, the heroku pipeline interface only offered 'staging' and 'production' as options. How do I create a 'test' stage in my pipeline? Are the docs out of date or am I misunderstanding the functionality?